# Checkbox title as link

Tags: forms

I want to make the checkbox title as link with target _blank but this doesn't seem working.

```
$form['approve'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => l(t('Approve conditions'), 'node/10'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

[image]

So the approve conditions should be a link

Comment: So why not a simple list ul  ? checkbox is for select something...

Comment: Do you mean the users should select the checkbox if they approve the conditions, and the link is for taking them to the page listing the conditions?

Comment: @kiamlaluno. Yes, i do mean it. Since it is not working, I have to do like this, which is not nice `$form['approve'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('<a href="/node/10" target= _blank>Approve conditions</a>'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );` and the title cannot be translated anymore.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, is the problem adding the target, and make it _blank?

Comment: I want the title to be a link and to be translated and the target = _blank. As you see if i add <a href ... in the title, it won't be translated

Comment: @kiamlaluno. Just added a screenshot to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't work on Drupal 8 because `l()` has been removed from Drupal 8. The correct code for Drupal 8 is closer to the following one.

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$form['approve'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => Link::fromTextAndUrl(new TranslatableMarkup('Approve conditions'), Url::fromUri('entity:node/10', ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']]))->toString(),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Alternatively, you can put the link in the description.

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$form['approve'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => new TranslatableMarkup('Approve conditions'),
  '#description' => new TranslatableMarkup('By clicking this checkbox, you <a href=":conditions">approve the conditions</a>', [':conditions' => Url::fromUri('entity:node/10', ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])]),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Keep in mind that, as said in the comments for [l() and url() are removed in favor of a routing based URL generation API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346779), if the shown code is used in a class using the [`StringTranslationTrait`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/trait/StringTranslationTrait/8.4.x) trait, instead of the `TranslatableMarkup` class you use `$this->t()`.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but when I change the 'entity : node/10' to 'entity : term-and-condition' then it is not working. BTW, how do you know to use link, Url and StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup in this case?

Comment: Ok the entity is for {entity_type}/{entity_id}, how about the url string?

Comment: How can I replace node/10 with term-and-condition?

Comment: ok just replace the 'entity:node/10' with 'base:/term-and-condition'. Many thanks guys